# Generating Ant build file for a project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a project written in Java using eclipse and I would like to generate an Ant build file for it. How can it be done? I constantly need to keep it synchronized with the source code, so that I could promote it along with the code to the common repository when with the project structure is modified.

I'm sorry for a stupid question like this. I've browsed across the forums, but still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your ant file is not too large can you post it ?
Not sure why you need to keep restructuring it ? What kind of project is this ? (EJB, WAR, EAR) and what are the project dependencies ?

Comment: The project build is managed entirely with eclipse now. What I want is creating (automatically) the ant build file, that would do the same thing, and placing it to the repository (the project is hosted on github). The application is quite simple and doesn't have any external dependencies.

Comment: Maybe you need to write your own ant buildfile. Here is how: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-81_basics.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have accidentally discovered the way to do it. It's quite simple:
Right click on the project -> Export -> Ant build file :)

Comment: It will be Eclipse specific build.xml, as it has ${ECLIPSE_HOME} variable. So it will be necessary to make additional refactore of this file.

Comment: It provides a little customization. You can get a build file that knows nothing about eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Ant build file and attach it to Eclipse http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-81_basics.htm

Comment: I need the tool, that would make it automatically. I don't want to maintain it with my own hands.

Comment: I am not sure it is possible.