# Eclipse Generated Build Files

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

I am using the ZK Studio plugin to create a web based project based on the ZK framework. Now, in order to deploy this project, all I do is right click on the project and select "Export" then select "WAR file". However, I would like build files to be created so that someone else can just make a change and run the build file to re-compile and create the WAR file automatically. I have been told that Netbeans does this automatically, and it seems so does eclipse since it allows me to just say "Export as WAR". However, I need to commit build files to the svn as well. How can I get this option through eclipse?

Thanks!

P.S. I have seen this question:
[Generating Ant build file for a project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753795/generating-ant-build-file-for-a-project-in-eclipse)
But I do not have that option when I right click for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Select build.properties file in project explorer view and from context menu (right click) select PDE Tools -> Create ant build file.

Same can be achieved through an ant task as well. See http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?nav=/4_2_0

Comment: I dont have a build.properties file

Comment: Then is not regular Eclipse plug-ins you are using. In fact, my bad, I didnt read it properly. If I got you right, you are creating some ZK stuido kind of project. Which is not an Eclipse plug-in or OSGi bundle.